# Switch type of repository in ASP.NET Core C# .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, appsettings

I want to use my Web API for different databases (SQL Server and MongoDb).
I have two generic repositories: EntityRepository<> and MongoRepository<>.
So that I have this code

```
builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(EntityRepository<>));
```

When I want to switch DB, I should enter

```
builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(MongoRepository<>));
```

and recompile application.

I want to switch it from appsettings.json

```
"SourceDb": {
"Entity": "EntityRepository",
"Mongo": "MongoRepository"
```

}

How can I refactor this code to switch generic repositories by strings from appsettings.json?
Or maybe you know better way to switch databases without recompilation.

Comment: Why not Inject both repositories, and use the one you will require?

Comment: Solution largely depends on how you know when to use which repository

Comment: What is the actual question? How to use either Mongo or EF based on some setting? Or use a different provider for different services? You can't solve either by just trying to register a single generic type

Comment: Besides, EF Core *already* abstracts the underlying database and even has a CosmosDB No-SQL provider, already provides disconnected operations, Unit-of-Work and optimistic concurrency. If you use one of the naive "generic repository" implementations you're getting the worst possible code for either relational databases or MongoDB. EF Core already caches all changes and persists/commits them when `SaveChanges` is called. This way, no database transactions are needed. Your MongoDB would have to behave the same.

Answer (score 2):

it seems you want to use two types of repositories at the same time, in this case, you should register two repo (**you needed two type interfaces**) and inject both to them.

**Update2:**
[Keyed DI services in dotnet 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-8#keyed-di-services)

**update1:**
and you can combine a factory with a delegate to done:

define interface :

```
public interface ILog
{
void log();
}
```

and class:

```
public class logtoFile: ILog
{void log(){//log to file}}

public class logtoDb: ILog
{void log(){//log to DataBase}}
```

so we need a delegate :

```
public delegate Ilog IlogResolved(int type);
```

and set ioc in startup:

```
builder.services.addScope<logtoFile>();
builder.services.addScope<logtoDb>();

builder.services.addScope<IlogResolved>
(
provider => type =>
{
  return type switch
   1=> provider.getService<logtoFile>(),
   2=> provider.getService<logtoDb>(),
   _ => throw new ArgumentException(nameof(type))
};
);
```

and then use it like this:

```
private readOnly IlogResolved _logResolvd;
public myclass(IlogResolved logResolvd)
{_logResolvd=logResolvd;}


public void DoSomthing()
{
 var logTofile=_logResolvd(1);
 var logToDb=_logResolvd(2);

 logTofile.log("log to file");
 logTofile.log("log to db");
}
```

Comment: so how can I switch between them?

Comment: first, you need to change the service constractor to get two types of repo, next, you can decide, which one, and when in the service.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write and extension method to your configuration service:

```
private static void SetRepository(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    string repo = configuration["SourceDb"];

    if (repo == "EntityRepository")
    {
        services.AddTransient<IRepository, EntityRepository>();
    }
    else
    {
        services.AddTransient<IRepository, MongoRepository>();
    }
}
```